# How can I make tx.executeSql() function sync with async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

How can I make `tx.executeSql(SQL, [], (tx, results)` be a sync function with sync/await?

I want to do some like this:

`tx.executesql` is async so my closeDB() (`closeDatabase()`) doesn't work because transaction is in progress.

```
await tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results)
```

but it doesn't work.

(see the outputs)

This is the warning I got at the end of the output:

```
C:\...name of proyect\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\ScrollView\InternalScrollViewType.js:46 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: error is not a function
TypeError: error is not a function
    at SQLitePlugin.close (blob:http://localhost:8081/7a5bb020-64e9-41f5-a654-e50e6b9f5827:93749:9)
    at _callee4$ (blob:http://localhost:8081/7a5bb020-64e9-41f5-a654-e50e6b9f5827:92942:54)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/7a5bb020-64e9-41f5-a654-e50e6b9f5827:23006:19)
.
.
.
.
```

```
async componentDidMount() {


    console.log('*COMIENZA componentDidMount');
    await this.consultarBD();
    await this.openBD();

    console.log('DataUsuarios es: ' + this.state.dataUsuarios);
    await this.insertarDatos();
    await this.closeDatabase();

    console.log('*TERMINA componentDidMount');

  }
```

```
 insertarDatos = async () =>{
    console.log('COMIENZA insertarDatos');
     await db.transaction((tx) => {
       console.log('Comienza Transaction');
        for(let i in this.state.dataUsuarios){
          const sql = `INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (
            '${this.state.dataUsuarios[i].id}', 
            '${this.state.dataUsuarios[i].nombre}',
            '${this.state.dataUsuarios[i].usuario}',
            '${this.state.dataUsuarios[i].password}',
            '${this.state.dataUsuarios[i].grupo}',
            '${this.state.dataUsuarios[i].faenas}'
          )`;
          console.log('antes de excute i es: ' + i);
          tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results) => {
           console.log('dentro de executesql i es: ' + i);
            if(results.rowsAffected > 0){
              console.log('¡Datos insertados en BD!');
            }else{
              console.log('¡No se puedieron insertar datos en la BD!');
            }(error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
            }
          });
        }
        console.log('termina transaccion');
    });
    
    console.log('TERMINA insertarDatos');

  }
```

OutPuts:

```
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:22 COMIENZA insertarDatos
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:88 Comienza Transaction
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:88 antes de excute i es: 0
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:88 antes de excute i es: 1
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:88 antes de excute i es: 2
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:88 antes de excute i es: 3
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:90 termina transaccion
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:112 TERMINA insertarDatos
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:128 Cerrando database ...
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\DrawerScreens\index.js:7 cannot close: transaction is in progress
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:91 dentro de executesql i es: 0
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:93 ¡Datos insertados en BD!
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:91 dentro de executesql i es: 1
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:93 ¡Datos insertados en BD!
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:91 dentro de executesql i es: 2
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:93 ¡Datos insertados en BD!
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:91 dentro de executesql i es: 3
C:\Users\josen\React-Projects\Ges\src\Screen\Login.js:93 ¡Datos insertados en BD!
```

Answer (score 4):

The **async/await** way to make `executeSql()`:

```
async function example() {
  let db = await SQLite.openDatabase(
    database_name,
    database_version,
    database_displayname,
    database_size
  );

  await db.transaction(async tx => {
     var [tx, results] = await tx.executeSql("SELECT * from TableName;");
     var row = results.rows.item(0); //get the first row assumed existed.
  });

  await db.close();
}
```

Comment: This is a concise answer but I see you have had to use two *var* declarations instead let or const. I tried to change this but Typescript whined about it. I see that you've used *let* further up. It's really tough to make async / await work with sqLite and to understand it. Especially the reason for the [tx, results] array. I can't get my head round the reason for tx appearing there.

Comment: @mwarren, `tx` is there because `executeSql` is an async method, maybe somewhere you got the result still need the `tx` to execute another SQL.

Comment: Not working as executeSql is expecting a callback function

Answer (score 3):

Try implementing it like this, wrapping it in a promise, you should be able to call this function with an `await`

```
  insertarDatos = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        try {
          /* Successful transaction */
          /* Make sure to call resolve when the transaction has finished
          */
          resolve()
        } catch (error) {
          /* Failed transaction */
          // if you reject any eventual errors, you can catch them when calling the function insertarDatos

          reject(error)
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

Now, if that doesn't work, it may be an issue with your `forin`. If that's the case, it may be useful to check out this [post](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404). It has a native implementation of an `async` foreach, which could be implemented as follows:

```
await asyncForEach(userlist, async (user, index) => {
     // do something with user and index

     // you can use await here
})
```

Comment: I like this answer. Gives you full control. And its simple

Answer (score -1):

```
async getSqlitedata(): {
   const data = await dbconn.executeSql("SELECT * from TableName;",[]);
   if (data.rows.lenth >0) {
       console.log(data.rows);
   }
}
```

it will return a object `{rows: {…}, rowsAffected: 0, insertId: undefined}`